# Calling a delegate on two functions

Tags: c#

Consider the following class:

```
class A
{
void f1(int a){}
void f2(int b){}
}
```

I would like to do the following:

```
A a = new A();
A b = new B();

Func f = A.f1(1); //A function that has already got arguments.
Func ff = A.f1(10); //A function that has already got arguments.

a.f(); //Calls a.f1(1);
a.ff(); //Calls a.f1(10);
b.f(); //Calls b.f1(1);
```

I don't think it works but I am happy if someone can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) to capture function arguments:

```
Action f = () => a.f1(1);
Action ff = () => a.f1(10);
```

And later you can call:

```
f();  // calls a.f1(1)
ff(); // calls a.f1(10)
```

If you want to call `f1` method on `a` or `b` instances (I assume you have `B : A` inheritance here), then you should use `Action<T>` delegate which will accept instance to call `f1` method on:

```
Action<A> f = x => x.f1(42);
```

And invoke this action with instace on which you want to run method `f1` with captured argument falue (42):

```
f(a); // calls a.f1(42)
f(b); // calls b.f1(42)
```

Comment: but this way I cannot do b.ff();

Comment: Action ff is not a method in class A, so `A.ff();` is not valid. You just need to do `ff();`.